# Bitmap is downscalling in large device with imageview

Tags: android, json, bitmap

I am in trouble with bitmap because when i parse image-url from json and set it to ImageView,it is small in size on larger device like Lenevo k3 Note. Is bitmap a good idea to use or is there any other approach to set the image parsed from json.             I have already set ImageView to wrap content as height and width to adjust accordingly..                                         The same bitmap object is larger but not accurate on small device why is this happing,I have done a lot of R & D but could not fix it. Please provide a better solution to the problem.. A well define solution will be appricated thanks in advance.

```
   //code to set the imageview with bitmap

                    String imageUrl=saving.getBankLogo()
                      Bitmap bitmap=getBitmapFromURL(imageUrl);

                    //resized Bitmap
                            Bitmap resizedBitmap=bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,bitmap.getWidth(),bitmap.getHeight(),false);
                            imgIcon.setImageBitmap(resizedBitmap);

                //code to get Bitmap from url
                     public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String imageUrl) {
                            Bitmap myBitmap;
                            Bitmap newBitMap;
                            try {

                                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
                                URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
                                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                                connection.setDoInput(true);
                                connection.connect();
                                InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();

                                BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                                bitmapOptions.inSampleSize = 1;
                                bitmapOptions.inScaled=true;

                            /*    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
                                int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
                                int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
                    */



                                 myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input, null, bitmapOptions);
                                /*myBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myBitmap, myBitmap.getHeight(),
                                        myBitmap.getWidth(), true);*/

                               /*  newBitMap = scaleToActualAspectRatio(myBitmap);

                                newBitMap=decodeFile(input);*/
                                input.close();



                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                return null;
                            }
                            return myBitmap;
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting ImageView to WRAP_CONTENT will make the ImageView to change its size according to the image or Bitmap used in it. This will cause bugs when comparing images on different devices because of their varying screen densities. A small sized device generally has mdpi density level making the Bitmap look bigger where as a large screen has the density level of hdpi or above making the Bitmap look smaller.

To make your UI look uniform across devices, set a particular width and height for your ImageView (make sure to set the dimensions in dp). Then, set the Bitmap as a source (src property in xml code) if you want to maintain its aspect ratio or set it as background if you want to cover the entire ImageView.

Visit the following links for more details:

http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html